# Showing images and inverse images don't invert each other

Tags: real-analysis, functions

While studying analysis I got the following:

> If $f : Z → Z$ is the map $f(x) = x^2$, then $f^{−1}({0, 1, 4}) = \{−2,−1, 0, 1, 2\}$.
>
> Note that $f$ does not have to be invertible in order for $f^{−1}(U)$
>   to make sense. Also note that images and inverse images do not quite
>   invert each other, for instance we have $f^{−1}(f({−1, 0, 1, 2})) \neq \{−1, 0, 1, 2\}$ (why?)

Even though it's not a formal question, the author put "why?" so we think about it, I did but I want to try and answer it formally as a general case (if this is doable). I know one counter example is enough to show that a statement isn't true but I would like both sides of things if possible.

For instance in this particular function this happens because $+x$ or $-x$ give the same result for $f(x)=x^2$ but is there a general way to state this for any function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, $f^{-1}(f(S)) = S$ holds iff $f$ is injective (and, of course, your example $x \mapsto x^2$ is not one of those).

Indeed, if $f: X \to Y$ is an injective function and $S \subset X$, the inclusion $S \subset f^{-1}(f(S))$ is obvious (because $f(s) \in f(S)$ for any $s \in S$ by definition). For the other inclusion, notice that any $s \in f^{-1}(f(S))$ satisfies $f(s) \in f(S)$, so that $f(s) = f(x)$ for some $x \in S$, and since $f$ is injective this means $s = x \in S$ as desired.

Conversely, if for every $S \subset X$ the inclusion  $f^{-1}(f(S)) = S$ holds, then $f(a) = f(b)$ for $a, b \in X$ implies that $f(b) \in f(\{a \})$, therefore $b \in f^{-1}(f(\{a\})) = \{a\}$, whence $a = b$, showing as desired that $f$ is injective.

Comment: thank you for this

Comment: @Sergio No problem!

Comment: @MatheusAndrade could you answer the first part of the statement? - "$f$ does not have to be invertible in order for $f^{−1}(U)$ to make sense". Why doesn't $f$ have to be invertible?

Comment: @PaulAsh if $f: X \to Y$ is a function and $U \subset Y$ is a subset of $Y$, $f^{-1}(U)$ is defined as the set of points in $X$ whose images are in $U$. That is, $x \in f^{-1}(U)$ if, and only if, $f(x) \in U$. Note that we never, at any point, asked for anything related to invertibility when defining $f^{-1}(U)$ - that's why $f$ doesn't have to be invertible in order for $f^{-1}(U)$ to make sense.

Comment: @MatheusAndrade Okay, that makes sense, thank you! One other question if you don't mind. Suppose $f : X \rightarrow Y$ is a function and $S \subset X$ and $U \subset Y$. Aren't we running the risk of defining the forward image as $f(S) := \{f(x) : x \in S\}$ and the inverse image as $f^{-1}(U) := \{x \in X : f(x) \in U\}$ if, say, $X$ and $Y$ contain sets as objects? Wouldn't that then make the notion of $f^{-1}$ existing ambiguous? Or would the context make up for it you think?

Comment: Oh, I suppose it's not a problem since $S$ and $U$ would then just be sets containing sets, so both definitions are still valid. But anyway, let me know what you think.